# salvar os dados vindos do parse (back4app) na memória do celular

Tags: java, android

estou tentando salvar os dados vindo do parse no aparelho, quando tem conexão com a internet ele funciona, mas quando não tem não funciona portanto os dados só aparecem quando tem internet

o parse oferece essa linha código para o procedimento

`ParseObject.pinAllInBackground(listOfObjects);`

a duvida é aonde implementa - lo
na mainActivity? no adapter?

Comment: Já tentou usar o SQLite?!

Comment: SQLite não, estou usando parse no meu app, e já esta pronto por isso não posso mudar meu banco de dados agr.

Comment: Entendi, o perse então esta no celular mas não esta persistindo os dados. Você tem que debugar seu código sem internet e ver o que está acontecendo, aliás debugar com e sem, para ver se está dando algum erro etc. Tenta verificar e melhorar sua pergunta, porque senão ninguém vai poder te ajudar.

Comment: Não aparece nenhum erro, apenas quero que o aplicativo salve os dados vindos do banco de dados offline no dispositivo.

Comment: Eu nunca pesisti informações no banco interno usando algo além do nativo. Você deve então dar uma lida na documentação desse tal "Parse".

Comment: https://docs.back4app.com/docs/android/how-to-build-an-android-app-on-back4app/

Comment: Como que você faz para pegar os dados do parse e mostrar no aplicativo?